# Karabiner: how to define combo mods?

Tags: karabiner

I'd like holding two home row letters to translate to holding a modifier.

<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> = <kbd>Cmd</kbd>
<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = <kbd>Alt</kbd>
<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>

The idea is taken from this [post](https://jasoncarloscox.com/blog/combo-mods/) which also describes how to do it using [QMK firmware](https://qmk.fm/).

My attempt was:

```
{
            "complex_modifications": {
                "parameters": {
                    "basic.simultaneous_threshold_milliseconds": 50,
                    "basic.to_delayed_action_delay_milliseconds": 500,
                    "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 1000,
                    "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 500,
                    "mouse_motion_to_scroll.speed": 100
                },
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "a",
                                    "simultaneous": [
                                        {
                                            "key_code": "s"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "to_if_held_down": [
                                    {
                                        "modifiers": [
                                            "left_gui"
                                        ],
                                        "repeat": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
...
        }
```

Just now I've also tried:

```
{
            "description": "",
            "manipulators": [
              {
                "from": {
                  "simultaneous": [
                    {

                      "key_code": "a"
                    },
                    {
                      "key_code": "s"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "to_if_held_down": [
                  {
                    "modifiers": [
                      "left_gui"
                    ],
                    "repeat": true
                  }
                ],
                "type": "basic"
              }
            ]
          }
```

Comment: Are you aware that those mods are only possible on the Atreus keyboard that is designed with a *customizable firmware* that facilitates  these types of mods?

Comment: The post describes the approach using customizable hardware, I was hoping that it can be done with Karabiner as well.

Comment: Right now this lacks any research. What have you tried so far yourself to set it up?

Comment: Added what I thought could have worked

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying this based on the same link as you, this is what I ended up with that works for me:

```
 {
  "description": "Press F and D together to act as Command",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "type": "basic",
      "from": {
        "simultaneous": [
          {"key_code": "f"},
          {"key_code": "d"}
        ],
        "simultaneous_options": {
          "detect_key_down_uninterruptedly": true,
          "key_down_order": "insensitive",
          "key_up_order": "insensitive",
          "to_after_key_up": []
        }
      },
      "to": [
        {"key_code": "left_command"}
      ],
      "parameters": {
        "basic.simultaneous_threshold_milliseconds": 50
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I've imported it into my Karabiner as a complex rule, but can't see it working in any way. I can see f and d printed to the terminal. If I hold them down, one of the letters get printed repeatedly. I did check that keyboards I'm using have `Modify events` enabled. What am I missing?